# JavaScript time compare

Tags: javascript, datetime, date, time

I have now the following code:

```
var d = new Date();
var curr_hour = d.getHours();
var curr_minute = d.getMinutes();
var curr_time = curr_hour + ":" + curr_minute;

var open_time = "17:00";

if(Date.parse ( curr_time ) > Date.parse ( open_time )){
   alert("Webshop is open");
} else {
   alert("Webshop is closed.");
}
```

What the code should do is.. if the current time is greater then 17:00 send the alert and if not, send the other alert.. All i get now is that it is closed.

Comment: For one, you're missing an `else`

Comment: Ahh.. yeah I fixed that, still not working.. (stupid lol)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need all that parsing, you already know `getHours()` method!

```
if(new Date().getHours() >= 17)
```

...that's it!

Comment: Very simple, and very usefull. Thanks Tomasz!

Comment: Ya, note however that this also picks up when the time is 17:00. You need to only get the time greater than 17:00. So, check the seconds and minutes as well. I posted the code in one of the answers

Answer (score 1):

You can't just parse time in `hh:mm` format. Give it an arbitrary date (Jan 1, 2012 in this case) to make it a full date object. The date doesn't matter as long as it's the same for both.

```
if(Date.parse('01/01/2012 ' + curr_time) > Date.parse ('01/01/2012 ' +  open_time)){
   console.log("open");
}else{
   console.log("closed");
}
```

A simpler approach would be to just compare the hours and minutes since that's what you have.

```
curr_hour > open_hour && curr_minute > open_minute
```

Answer (score 0):

Why create date objects? Just use basic math.

```
var d = new Date();
var curr_hour = d.getHours();
var curr_minute = d.getMinutes();
var curr_time = curr_hour + curr_minute/60;

var open_time = 17;
var openClosed = curr_time > open_time ? "Open" : "Closed";

alert("Webshop is " + openClosed + ".");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var d = new Date();
var curr_hour = d.getHours();
var curr_minute = d.getMinutes();
var curr_second = d.getSeconds();

if((curr_hour > 17) || (curr_hour == 17 && curr_minute == 0 && curr_second == 0 )){
   alert("Webshop is open");
} else {
   alert("Webshop is closed.");
}
```

Comment: Ah ya... we will need to check the == 17:00:00 condition separately. Just amended